# How can i add another authentication parameter to Spring Security authentication login_security_check?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I am working with Spring security authentication but I cannot seem to find where the credentials are being authenticated. I need to add the functionality to authenticate using username + password + isEnabled parameter. Where does the login_security_check take place? and how can I edit this?

Comment: It depends. What does your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter look like?

Comment: Where is your code? What type of security? How can anyone answer this?

Answer (score 0):

Database-backed UserDetailsService for authentication with Spring Security has a method named loadUserByUsername().
This method can be overridden to customize the process of finding the user at the time on login.
You can add the code to check if the user is enabled or not in this method.
For learning more about this check the link.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database